# basic configuration for my first jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am just learning this plugin, read the wikis, then downloaded the demos but maybe something wrong on my php-configuration, because it only shows the jqGrid when request server in XML , meanwhile in JSON not yet.

anyway, 
i'm trying to understand the basic configuration for jqGrid, then firebug give me this error

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function
```

then i put 1 line in head section, and its works

```
<script src="http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I dont understand, meanwhile that src is empty. and also, if i replace the src with www.stackoverflow.com or www.google.com its works

meanwhile, if i use grid.locale-en.js in my local server, it doesnt works

i put my first jqGrid html [here](http://www.padusi.com/ani/files/learn.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid.locale-en.js needs to come before you call the jqGrid script. Ex

```
<script src="~/Scripts/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can also make your life easier by setting a jqGrid property of:

```
data: mydata,
```

rather then loading it in via your loop.

jsfiddle example of doing so: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hekai/QEzhr/1/

Comment: i put it before jqGrd, but it doesnt works. if I put after it, its works :) and i dont understand, if put src="" (empty) it works with error : syntax error : <!DOCTYPE ....

and per your advise i try your data: mydata, and put var mydata on the top of script, but the table is blank.

Comment: Here are the instillation instructions for jqGrid. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install

Comment: I linked above a JSFiddle showing you an example of the `data: mydata`